# Can I run Ubuntu ?

Tags: installation, system-requirements

My system specifications are as follows:

1 GB Ram

Intel core 2 duo processors, 1.80 Ghz

100 GB hard Disk

32 bit

ATI Radeon Graphics card.

With the above requirements is it possible to run Ubuntu in my laptop, currently it is running windows vista. If yes, then please specify which version of Ubuntu?

Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can run Ubuntu, but you will most likely benefit from using a lightweight fork of Ubuntu instead, such as Lubuntu or Kubuntu.
http://www.lubuntu.net/
http://www.kubuntu.org/

Comment: or Xubuntu http://xubuntu.org/

Answer (score 1):

You can install and run the 32-bit version of [Ubuntu 13.10 - Saucy Salamander](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/thank-you?release=latest&bits=32&distro=desktop&status=zeroc) .

The minimum requirements for this OS are,

- 384 MB - RAM
- 700 MHz Processor
- 5 GB Hardrive space

Your system pass all of the above requirements.

Answer (score 1):

If you only have 1GB RAM i wouldn't recommend you to use Unity. Try to check out other Ubuntu-distros. Take a look at Xubuntu or Lubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

**YES**, you can. Some eceptions:

1. With 1GB of RAM is better to consider upgrade of RAM, it si very cheap. 
   If upgrade is not possible, consider to use Ubuntu without Unity desktop environment or some lightweight version of Ubuntu (Xubuntu, Lubuntu or Kubuntu). I prefer Xubuntu.
2. It is good to consider your graphics card. Some hybrid Radeon cards has weak support for Linux in general. Please tell us more what exactly is type of your Radeon. Recomended version of ubuntu, kernel and graphics driver depends very much on that. Anyway, if you don't have Unity, in most cases you can use native non-3D drivers.
3. As you would have a older notebook with low amount of memory, consider to make final tweeks about disk **swappiness** and other performance tweeks to extend your battery life.

Ubuntu can give you a great value in comparison with W Vista.